# SNMP+ SHELL SCRIPTING+ php

Tags: php, shell, snmp

I am running an snmp command on my bash script

snmpwalk -v2c -c community 192.168.122.15 .1.3.6.1.4.1.14823.2.2.1.4.1.2.1.39

Now when I call this script via php it shows

**snmpwalk: relocation error: /usr/lib/libnetsnmp.so.15: symbol RAND_bytes, version OPENSSL_1.0.0 not defined in file libcrypto.so.1.0.0 with link time reference**

I am new to scripting.
Thanks in advance :)

Comment: I do not know about snmp but there is one thing wrong for sure. Was it an accident or did you have a dot in your code .1.3.6.1.4.1.14823  did the command work before? Do you have mod-ssl installed? what platform are you using? all this has to be included in the question.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like *either* you have multiple versions of snmpwalk on your system and different PATH between php and bash environments causing one or the other to be picked up, *and/or* the runtime library search path (e.g. LD_LIBRARY_PATH environment variable) is different between the two environments and it is picking up one of two versions of libcrypto.so on your system; one has the missing symbol and the other does not.